# SQL query using date() function

Tags: orientdb-2.1

This is OrientDb 2.1.4.

The following query works fine:

*select from SyncableHist where history_date <= date('2016-04-12 21:25:17','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')*

and returns as expected three records and each records has the value of history_date = '2016-04-12 21:25:17'. The history_date is a DATETIME type.

However this does not return any records:

*select from SyncableHist where history_date = date('2016-04-12 21:25:17','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')*

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiarized with orientDb, but try to cast history_date like `select from SyncableHist where date(history_date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = date('2016-04-12 21:25:17','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a valid syntax in OrientDb. Thank you anyway...

Comment: Try this one: `select from SyncableHist where history_date.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = '2016-04-12 21:25:17'`

Comment: That works, which is strange because history_date is not a String type, but DateTime. Also, using format() function disables the index on history_date.

Comment: Good to know. I wrote a answer to your post. Please, mark as the correct answer to the next one who will have the same doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Format your date to string before compare. Not sure why, but probably have something extra like miliseconds or your database can't compare both this way.

`select from SyncableHist where history_date.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') = '2016-04-12 21:25:17'`

Comment: However, it still does not explain why  history_date <= date('2016-04-12 21:25:17','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') works. Also, if there is a index on history_date, it is not used by the query because of history_date.format().